# Whats wrong with my ConnectionString? When I test my API in Postman I get an error

Tags: c#, database, postgresql, connection-string

The first time I'm trying to Connect my Database (PostgreSQL - pgaAdmin).

I did my ConnectionString in: appsettings.json. After, I did an APIController.

I wanted to test my API in Postman. I got an error when I'm trying to test:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is known (ERROR CODE: 11001)

I suppose I did something wrong with my connection string but I don't know where is it.

[image: My ConnectionString]

[image: Database Informations]

[image: The Error]

Comment: As per tagging guidelines, please do not put tags in your question title. If you're a new user, please be sure to take the [tour] and read [ask] and associated topics to ensure you understand the conventions for posting on this site.

Comment: See: https://www.connectionstrings.com/postgresql

Answer (score 3):

Try to use "Server=localhost" instead of "Host=localhost" in connection string

Comment: See also: https://www.connectionstrings.com/postgresql

Comment: I rewrited my ConnectionString with the link (Uwe Keim's Link) and it is works. Thank you so Much!
(The new conenction string: 
 "User ID=postgres;Password=asd123;Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=StudyO;Pooling=true;Connection Lifetime=0;" )